# How thick should my plywood desk be?

Tags: plywood, desk

I am looking to build a  desk that will be 220cm x 55cm  (*86 inches x 21 inches*).

It'll need to hold at least a PC a games console, and three Monitors.

How thick does it need to be?

Comment: The thickness is going to depend a lot on where you're planning to support it. You may wish to edit you're question to include that information.

Comment: 1cm if ribbed, 2cm (3/4") if the sheet is the only span support.

Comment: It also depends on what you're planning on putting on it. [The Sagulator](https://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) is a great tool for determining how much flex there will be in a shelf, which is, effectively, what your desk is.

Comment: I can't help but notice that the size is close to a door, which are very sturdy and cheap and make great desks.

Comment: If you're building a 7 foot long desk with just supports at the far ends then 1 inch minimum.

Comment: @dandavis That is quite a slim door and I wouldn't claim it to be anything close to normal in the states here...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: look for a bifold door (like a closet/pantry one), or rip a wider one to fit. A solid door at habitat re-store is $10, which is a lot less than a 96" long thick plywood sheet...

Comment: For that length I use 1.5in thick wooden counter tops, available -for instance- in the "as-is" section of your local Swedish furniture store.

Comment: As you can see, the question is unanswerable. Please provide a full design plan.

Comment: There is no "right" or "wrong" answer here.  It depends on many factors including how sturdy YOU want it to be.  You can easily make a desktop out of 1/4" floor underlayment and that might be OK for some uses but it would drive me nuts.  I have a desk that I made out of 2x 3/4" plywood and I'm very pleased with it.  Yes, it's likely overkill but you just never know when you might want to park a car on top of your desk!

Comment: Type of legs and their support pieces might be more important than thickest of top.  2 inch top with unsupported legs will be less dependable to stay up than 3/8 with good legs and support.